# Twitter Android App Homepage Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments

good day! may i ask about the picture below what kind of android layout is it? on some other devices the picture of twitter homepage is changing. I want to create same homepage for my app. Thanks! I cant post image so i tried posting the link.

[image]

Comment: What is so special about that layout??Two `TextViews`, Two `Buttons` and one background image!

Comment: @AbhishekV how about the interchanging background image?

Comment: Well you can change the background image of any layout dynamically...either you can put 3-4 images in drawable folder and can change it randomly...or if you are using the image from server, then if the image gets changed in the server, layout image also changes.

Comment: i think i get your point with randomly changing the background image but how to do that? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if you have a `Layout` something like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout" >

 //Other view elements like buttons, TextViews

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can dynamically change the `background` of the `layout` using below code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
        int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};

        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(images[getRandomNumber()]);
    }


    private int getRandomNumber() {
        //Note that general syntax is Random().nextInt(n)
        //It results in range 0-4
        //So it should be equal to number of images in images[] array
        return new Random().nextInt(4);
    }



}
```

Store the images in an `array`. In the `onCreate`, `getRandomNumber` methods returns a `random number` using which you can get a random image from the `array` and put it as a background to `layout`

Comment: i will try this now thanks. i will  keep posting.

Comment: thank you i have another question thanks to this.